# SAS EG fastest way to copy/paste columns of table/query to excel/text

Tags: sas

So far what I do is run query builder, click preview, copy content of select, paste in excel, ctrl+H replace "          t1." by "" and replace "," by "".

That's not very elegant and takes a few seconds for each table, is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: That sounds awful, but it's unclear what you're doing.  You're pasting the contents of a SAS select into Excel?  Is there a reason you're not using SAS's native export to excel functionality?

Comment: PROC EXPORT or ODS EXCEL can be used to automate the export option.

Comment: I think you mean that you are copying the SQL code that SAS generates from the query builder - and not the results of the query. Can you explain why you are doing this - meaning what is your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you simply want a 'list' of the columns that are output/referenced in your query (from Query Builder).

If you are actually running the Query Builder step and a new table is created, you can query the DICTIONARY tables for information about that. For example, you could run this in a separate program:

```
PROC SQL;

SELECT
    name AS Column_Name
FROM
    DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
WHERE
    libname = 'LIBRARY' AND /* Change to the name of the library the table is in. */
    memname = 'TABLE'; /* Change to the name of the new table */

QUIT;
```

So, if you have a query like:

```
SELECT
   Column_A,
   Column_B
FROM
   LIBRARY.TABLE;
```

The query I provided atop will give you:

```
Column_A
Column_B
```

Which you can simply copy and paste - and not need to replace any characters.